# My Add-Ins tab dissapeared in MS Word 2010

Tags: microsoft-word-2010

I had a Print to DMS option in my Add-Ins tab. One day the tab is gone. If I go to Options\Customize Ribbon\All Tabs, there is no Add-Ins in the list. It is in the Main Tab listing on the right and it is checked. The COM Add-in is in the Active Application Add-ins.

Answer (score 0):

Go to `File` -> `Options` -> `Add-Ins`.

Is your add-in listed there as disabled?

If so, select the `Disabled Items` option in the `Manage` drop-down list at the bottom of the dialog, then click the `Go` button. You can try to re-enable your add-in from there. Restart Word, the `Add-Ins` tab should be displayed when an add-in is successfully loaded.

Comment: It is not in the disabled list. I should also mention that we are working on a terminal server. Some users do have the Add-Ins on their ribbon.

Comment: Do you see your add-in anywhere in the list?

Comment: Yes, it is in the Active Application Ad-ins list. And it is checked in the COM Add-Ins box.

Comment: I'd also like to mention that the Add-Ins tab is in all other modules of Office 2010 (Excel, Outlook, Powerpoint, etc.) Just Word lost the tab.